# Prevent a Semantic-UI Modal modal from closing via the close icon

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

I am able to prevent a modal being closed as per the [example in the docs](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#forcing-a-choice) by setting `closable: false`. But if I include a close icon in my html then this is not picked up as a deny action and goes ahead and closes the modal, no matter what.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1sf6oxu/1/)

I presume that this is because the [DOM Settings](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#settings) for a modal look like this:

```
selector    : {
  close    : '.close, .actions .button',
  approve  : '.actions .positive, .actions .approve, .actions .ok',
  deny     : '.actions .negative, .actions .deny, .actions .cancel'
},
```

You can see that `.close` is not in the deny selector.

So how can I have the `.close` icon fire the onDeny callback? (Note. I tried wrapping `.close.icon` in an `.actions` class but this breaks the modal.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change the settings when you initialize the module. I've tried it here http://jsfiddle.net/b1sf6oxu/7/

```
$('.modal').modal({
    selector: {
        close: '.actions .button',
        deny: '.actions .negative, .actions .deny, .actions .cancel, .close'
    },
    // ...
}
```